# Fetch data in flat list from Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I have a structure of data i want to fetch and display in a Flat List here is my data.

```
-Lt10FlMt0xtru36Ztmb
                  name : "Hello"
-Lt0pdC5Ikwd-ZWNBiYJ
                  name : "Coke"
-Lt0paPi_-zkCelfoisM
                  name : "Pespsi"
```

Here is my code:

```
  readUserData = () => {

        firebase.database().ref('Brands/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            const userdata = snapshot.val();

            //  Alert.alert("Helo" , userdata);
            this.setState({
              getListbrands : userdata

            })
            Alert.alert("Data" , JSON.stringify(this.state.getListbrands))


        });

    }
```

and here i am setting data in Flat list but it is not showing any thing please guide.

```
{
  this.state.getListbrands &&
  <FlatList
  data={this.state.getListbrands}
  keyExtractor={(a, b) => b.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text style={{color:'#000'}}>{item.name}</Text>
  )}

/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`FlatList` component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) expects an **array** of data. The value of your snapshot is an object, and not an array.

If you want to use an array of the values of each child node, you can get that with:

```
firebase.database().ref('Brands/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    userdata = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) {
        userdata.push(snapshot.val());
    })
    ...
```

You can then set this array to the `FlatList`.

Comment: What isn't working about it? Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient debugger, so to get the best help make sure you tell us exactly what happens when you run the code in a debugger, or by adding copious log statements.

Comment: This would work using .once, but my understanding is that will pull data only once as the name states... but .on returns someting differente and this approach does not work, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  this.state.getListbrands &&
  <FlatList
  data={this.state.getListbrands}
  keyExtractor={(a, b) => b.toString()}
  renderItem={(item) => (
    <Text style={{color:'#000'}}>{item.name}</Text>
  )}

/>
}
```

change like this.i think **item** in here is not a object.please try. it will work. thank you.